# Creating a trigger to move data from one table to the another in DB2

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, move, tivoli

I currently using IBM Tivoli to discover desktops etc on our network.

When it comes back with the SNMP information for the asset tag it puts in the wrong table.

I need to create a trigger that would look at the first say 9 characters and if they equalled a true asset tag to move it to another table.

I.e.

Snmpsys table 
under that is SYSCONTACT.

It needs to go to
CITEMPLATE to Conact to Asset Tag.

Comment: Does it have to be a trigger? sounds like a candidate for a batch job to me.

Comment: Can't Tivoli be convinced to put the data in the right table in the first place?

Comment: Have fun reading up on triggers - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0007038.htm

Comment: Trigger would be nice.  Need it to happen on a constant basis.

Comment: The SNMP field is configured on the server itself.  And with 30000 objects to discover I need to be able to change it on the DB end.    Did some reading on Triggers,  just need a better understanding of it.  Thanks